# Generating all subsets using Gosper's Hack (Bankers sequence)

Tags: java, subset

I have a method that generates all subsets of an array, what I want to try and implement is the same sort of method but doing it using binary. Gosper's Hack seems to be the best idea but I have no idea how to implement it. The code below works to generate all subsets.The subsets can be unknown (https://i.stack.imgur.com/mx9oP.jpg) this shows an output after a couple of seconds of running. Thanks for any advice

```
int m = prop.length;
int list = (1 << m);
for(long i = 1; i<list; i++) {
   final List sub = new ArrayList<>();
   for(long j=0; j<m; j++) {
      if((i & (1<<j)) > 0) {      
         sub.add(j);
      }
   }
   Collections.sort(sub);
   System.out.println(sub);
}
```

EDIT: As I have not worded the question correctly, what I need as output is:

```
2  1  0
0  0  1 = 0 
0  1  0 = 1
```

etc.

Comment: what is your problem? That generating all subsets are slow or another?

Comment: anyway, `Collections.sort(sub)` is not necessary here, because items are added into `sub` in order thay exist in initial array, so sorting is waste of time.

Comment: Ok cool, ill take that bit out.. Yes because of the program it needs to be as fast as possible and generating them this way is not optimal.

Comment: (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_number_system#Applications) This is the only method I found that describes it but it is difficult to understand

Comment: If you need to generate *all possble* subsets, nothing else could be noticeable faster, because number if subsets depends exponentially on input size (e. g. for 30 elements there exists ~1Bn subsets, for 40 elements - 10^12 etc)

Comment: The link you just provided states about k-combinations, not all possible subsets. K-kombinations are subsets containing exactly k items.

Comment: http://applied-math.org/subset.pdf This paper describes how it is faster and that is reason for implementing this function but the code in the paper is not clear also.

Comment: you can generate subsets using any possible method, but their number won't be smaller than it should be, exactly 2^n - 1, which grows very fast as input grows.

Comment: @Relentless, if you're asking how to generate all k-subsets of an n-set, then see my answer below. The algorithm essentially visists all binary sequences of length n containing exactly k ones in a clever way (without going through all 2^n sequences). If my algorithm is not good enough, I highly recommend Volume of Knuth's treatise which is probably the best resource out there.

Comment: A good exercise is to try to come up with a simple recursive algorithm for the problem. Hint: If you know how to generate all (k-1)-subsets, how would you generate all k-subsets? (There are many different ways to do this, of course.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I'd like to note that **it's not clear what exactly is it that you're trying to achieve; please consider clarifying the question**. I'll assume that you'd like to generate all *k*-subsets of an *n*-set. The problem can be easily reduced to that of generating all *k*-subsets of *{1,2,...,n}* (i.e. it suffices to compute all *k*-subsets of indices).

## An algorithm for generating *k*-subsets of an *n*-set

A while back I wrote [this](https://github.com/blazs/subsets) implementation of a method (which I rediscovered few years ago) for generating all *k*-subsets of an *n*-set. Hope it helps. The algorithm essentially visists all binary sequences of length *n* containing exactly *k* ones in a clever way (without going through all 2^n sequences); see [the accompanying note](https://github.com/blazs/subsets/blob/master/subsets.pdf) describing the algorithm, which contains detailed description, pseudocode, and a small step-by-step example.

I think the time complexity is of the order *O(k {n choose k})*. I do not yet have a formal proof for this. (It is obvious that any algorithm will have to take *Omega({n choose k})* time.)

The code in C:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void subs(int n, int k);

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if(argc != 3) return 1;
    int n, k;

    n = atoi(argv[1]); k = atoi(argv[2]);
    subs(n, k);

    return 0;
}

void subs(int n, int k)
{
    int *p = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*k);
    int i, j, r;

    for(i = 0; i < k; ++i) p[i] = i; // initialize our ``set'' 
    // the algorithm
    while(1)
     {  // visit the current k-subset
        for(i = 0; i < k; ++i)
            printf("%d ", p[i]+1);
        printf("\n");

        if(p[0] == n-k) break; // if this is the last k-subset, we are done 

        for(i = k-1; i >= 0 && p[i]+k-i == n; --i); // find the right element 
        r = p[i]; ++p[i]; j = 2; // exchange them 
        for(++i; i < k; ++i, ++j) p[i] = r+j; // move them 
     }
    free(p);
}
```

## References

If this is not efficient enough, I highly recommend Knuth's [Volume 4 of The Art of Comouter Programming](http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~uno/taocp.html), where he deals with the problem extensively. It's probably the best reference out there (and fairly recent!).

You might even be able to find a draft of the fascicle, TAOCP Volume 4 Fascicle 3, *Generating All Combinations and Partitions* (2005), vi+150pp. ISBN 0-201-85394-9, on Knuth's homepage (see his news for 2011 or so).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, its really helpful! I will look at the book!

Comment: @blazs I'm trying to understand how the algorithm works but not able to dry run it completely. would you mind showing how it is working with the example. The coding flow.

Comment: There's an example in the PDF I linked in the post. If that doesn't do it for you, let me know---I can prepare a more detailed example.

Comment: @blazs thanks. Its weird that somehow I understood the algorithm but not able to follow the code how its been done. For instance the line to find the the right element within code. I tried dry running it with example but couldn't follow. It will be really great if you could help me in understanding the code flow with an example. Thanks again for this answer. The best I found learning gospers hack.